# If I use the monk's ability to use dexterity instead of strength for melee, can I choose not to use the monks martial art die?

Tags: dnd-5e, monk

I’m trying to make a a Kensei Monk / Samurai Fighter multi-class, making it DEX based and using the longsword as my kensei weapon. Can I use my DEX instead of STR without having to use the monk's martial art die, as that would lead to a reduction in damage?

Comment: Welcome to the stack Duncan, take the [tour] when you have a moment. You’ve tagged this question with the generic [dungeons-and-dragons] tag, which is used for question about the franchise as a whole. Which *edition* of D&D are you playing? It look like it’s probably 5th, but I wanted to make sure before retagging the question.

Comment: 5e is what I’m playing

Answer (score 14):

### Yes, you can use Dex and the weapon's normal damage

The relevant rules here are two of the benefits from the Monk's martial arts feature (emphasis added):

> - You **can** use Dexterity instead of Strength for the attack and damage rolls of your unarmed strikes and monk weapons.
> - You **can** roll a d4 in place of the normal damage of your unarmed strike or monk weapon. [...]

Both of which grant you a choice to upgrade. This might not typically come up often, monks rarely want to use strength and at least after 5th level a d6 is equivalent or better to most of the typical monk weapons. Though not being able use the weapon's normal damage would make using weapons (and doubly so being a Kensei monk) nearly pointless.

Comment: I mean, the desire to use Dex on the attack but use the weapon die instead of Martial Arts comes up for almost every monk. At low level, many monk weapons are better than using the MA die, and in my experience most monks use a quarterstaff or spear (in Versatile mode) right up to 11th level unless they find an appropriate magic weapon first.

Answer (score 0):

### Yes this works

1. Because you are Kensei and selected longsword as one of your Kensei weapons, **longsword is one of your monk weapons**.
2. Because you are a monk **you can use Dexterity instead of Strength when using your monk weapons**.
3. Ergo, you can use Dexterity instead of Strength when using the longsword. These **attacks by default use the longsword's normal damage die** (1d8 when used one-handed, 1d10 when used two-handed, due to the *versatile* property).

You optionally **can** use your martial arts die to replace the longsword's damage die, but you are not forced to:

> You **can** roll a d4 in place of the normal damage of your unarmed strike or monk weapon. This die changes as you gain monk levels, as shown in the Martial Arts column of the Monk table.

As the table on PHB p. 77 shows, only starting from level 17, your Martial Arts die will be a d10 and preferable to the d8 of the longsword when wielded one-handed.

---

#### Rules and citations

The **longsword** is a *martial melee weapon* with 1d8 slashing damage and the following properties: *Versatile (1d10)*. As a melee weapon without the *finesse* propterty, it normally requires Strength for attack and damage roles, PHB p. 176

> **Attack Rolls and Damage**. You add your Strength modifier to your attack roll and your damage roll when attacking with a melee weapon

As a monk of any kind you gain the Martial Arts feature on level one which gives you this ability (PHB, p. 78)

> You gain the following benefits while you are unarmed or wielding **only monk weapons** (...):
>
> - You can **use Dexterity instead of Strength** for the attack and damage rolls of your unarmed strikes and monk weapons.

As a Kensei monk, you gain the Path of the Kensei feature on level three which gives you this ability (XgtE, p. 34):

> **Kensei Weapons**. Choose two types of weapons to be your kensei weapons: one melee weapon and one ranged weapon. Each of these weapons can be any simple or martial weapon that lacks the heavy and special properties. The longbow is also a valid choice. You gain proficiency with these weapons if you don't already have it. **Weapons of the chosen types are monk weapons for you.**

Because the longsword is a simple or martial melee weapon and lacks the heavy and special properties, it is eligible to be chosen as your Kensei weapon.

Answer (score -1):

Something you might not have considered: Unless you have an effect that tells you to deal damage on a miss, you deal your damage *if you hit*. This means that the damage you typically deal is your average damage roll *multiplied by* the probability that you hit (the number of d20 faces that result in a hit divided by 20, which can be anywhere from 5% to 95%, since you always hit on a roll of 20 and never hit on a roll of 1). Each point of attack bonus your Dexterity modifier provides that's more than your Strength modifier would provide is an increase to the probiability that you hit, adjusting it by 5%.

So as an example, if you expect to deal 1d6+4 damage 65% of the time, you can *expect* to deal 65% of 7.5 damage on average, which is around 4.875 damage for each attack you make. If you can only expect to hit 50% of the time with your Strength modifier and you expect to deal 1d10+1 damage, then that's 50% of the average damage roll of 6.5, or a typical expected 3.25 damage per attack you make.
This means that, if your Dexterity modifier is sufficiently higher than your Strength modifier, it doesn't matter which damage die you use until you start running against damage reduction, but as far as I'm aware, damage reduction halves the damage in both circumstances equally, still giving the advantage to the attack made with the Dexterity modifier.

You deal less damage on a miss with a maul than you do on a hit with a tree branch.
Of course, as Someone_Evil's answer notes, you're given the *option* of replacing your damage die with the martial arts damage die, so it's a moot point.

Comment: This answer seems to be answering a different question than what was actually being asked. The question is about forgoing the martial arts die (in favor of the Kensei weapon's natural damage die) while still using the character's Dex modifier to attack and damage rolls.